# How to add part in eagle board that doesn't have corresponded in the schematic "jumpers"?

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, jumper

I am using Eagle to design single side board and I want to use smd jumpers to connect between some points.
So basicly I don't want to add those smd jumpers as a component to the circuit in the schematic, I just want to be able to add them whenever I need without jumping every time to the schematic window and add them.
Just add them from the pcb window directly.

I have tried to search this but couldn't find something useful.

Comment: You will need to add them to the schematic.

Comment: :( There must be anyway to do it, technically speaking jumpers are not part of the schematic, right>

Comment: Technically speaking any component on the PCB should be part of the schematic... (even mechanical bits like holes and heatsinks!)

Comment: But jumper is not something that you can decide about in the schematic design phase, actually it is impossible to predict how many you want and what size would fit the need. It is considered as a bridge or if you would like, it just a wire in the schematic.

Comment: But it is a component on the PCB - it's nothing like a wire in the schematic because on the unpopulated PCB, the two regions of the net broken by the jumper are not physically connected. There is nothing wrong with going back and forth between the schematic and PCB. Initially what you can do is route the board. If you find the need for a jumper, add it to the schematic.

Comment: (p.s. I don't know why the question is getting downvoted, it is a reasonable think to ask!)

Comment: @TomCarpenter, me too !!!!!!

Comment: This sounds like the querent wants to add a jumper to the PCB and have it backannotate to his schematic, no?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I am not sure about the effect on the schematic, may be this is a good thing or may be not, I am not expert with eagle just start to use it 5 weeks ago!

Comment: You add everything to the schematic. That's the right way to do it. There's nothing shameful about **TEST POINTS**. There's even a library for that.

Comment: @Janka I just wanted to save some time by reducing the moving between the two windows nothing more, thanks

Comment: You are going to lose that time later, when you long forgot those test points and have to look up where they connect. It's much easier to do that in the schematic than on the board. Even with having eagle trace them to the nearest other component pad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To figure it out you need to understand how EAGLE works. Each device you find in library consists of three components - package, or board footprint with pads (through hole or SMD), symbol with pins, and correspondence between package and pins.

You *can* add package to board without adding symbol to schematics, but you will not be able to connect to its pads *properly*, and DRC will give you "overlapping" errors.

The right way is to add jumper to schematics, connect its pads respectively, and wire pads at the board level with tracks. All other ways is hacking, which may lead to

- your mistakes, and tool will not be able to advise you what is wrong;
- errors in DRC, and you may not be able to find the issue quickly.

EAGLE is a powerful tool, but please refrain misusing it. You will spend much more time figuring out why EAGLE gives you errors, or why your board does not work properly. Just follow rules and design board the way EAGLE supports.

Thus the answer is

You **must** add jumper to schematic, and wire it as needed at both schematic and board levels.

Comment: Upvoted this because it focuses on the importance of DRC (and ERC). Muhammad Nour, the correct way to use Eagle and other design tools is to ERC and DRC often, so you find mistakes quickly.

Comment: Ok, I think I have to follow the rules, just wanted to save some time !

Answer (score 6):

Another idea is to represent the jumpers as short wires of the top routing layer, using manual routing.

[image: A PCB layout, manually routed with top layers used to model jumpers]

This way, jumpers won't be modeled in the schematic editor. Also, you are free to choose the desired length.

You can also use them to connect isolated parts of a polygon together; see the second-leftmost and rightmost jumper in the picture above.

Note that Eagle will see the solder points as vias, not pads, so the via size must be changed to ease soldering.

Comment: The problem is I am using smd jumpers as they tend to be easier to handle and they have fixed size so this method wouldn't be very efficient.  thanks